# Initializing an array member of a struct by name

Tags: c

I have a struct that looks something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c[5];
    uint32_t d;
} MY_STRUCT_T;
```

I want to initialize `c`, by name, to a non-zero value. I want everything else to be 0.

If `c` were not an array, I could do:

```
static MY_STRUCT_T my_struct = {.b = 1};
```

And I know I can do this:

```
static MY_STRUCT_T my_struct = {.c[0]=5,
    .c[1]=5,
    .c[2]=5,
    .c[3]=5,
    .c[4]=5};
```

but I was wondering if there was a more elegant syntax of which I am unaware:
Something like:

```
static MY_STRUCT_T my_struct = {.c[] = {5,5,5,5,5}};
```

I have read the following, but they don't answer this question:
[Initializing a struct to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152160/initializing-a-struct-to-0) 

[Initialize/reset struct to zero/null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891720/initialize-reset-struct-to-zero-null) 
[A better way to initialize a static array member of a class in C++ ( const would be preferred though )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108321/a-better-way-to-initialize-a-static-array-member-of-a-class-in-c-const-would) 

[How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value)

Comment: Little difference between this and [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201101/2410359) aside from the `.c=` part.

Answer (score 3):

So I wrote this question and then experimented for a while and found that the following would work:

```
static MY_STRUCT_T my_struct = {.c={5,5,5,5,5}};
```

Comment: I think `static MY_STRUCT_T my_struct = {.c={5}};` works too.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: This will initialize all but first element of `c` array member with zeros (just like in ordinary array initialization).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: I think I missed the logic then :(

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the initialization logic is simple, *if any value of any member is initialized, then all other values not expressly initialized to some value, are initialized to zero by default* `.c={5};` is equivalent to `.c={5,0,0,0,0};` and `.c={5,5};` is equivalent to `.c={5,5,0,0,0};`

Answer (score 0):

OP has 3 goals: 1) field array size is fixed width, 2) initialization like `{7,7,7,7,7}` is fixed width, 3) `c`  to a non-zero value.  As #1 and #2 have their sizes *independent* coded, 2 of the 3 goals can be met, but not all 3 - that is tricky.

What is to prevent/warn about `MY_STRUCT_T my_struct = {.c = {5,5,5,5,5}};` not meeting goals should `uint32_t c[5];` later become `uint32_t c[6];`?  Nothing really.

Lacking a *maintainable* coding paradigm, consider [this - copy one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201164/2410359)

Comment: Yes, the summary is correct. That linked idea is not idea because I actually have to call that `for` loop code segment.